# ASP.NET Uploading file over 300KB~ makes browser lose connection

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, web-config, connection

I've been running my image-uploading site for about a month now. I haven't touched the script lately and this problem that occurs now never happened before, with even bigger uploads.
**When uploading a file with a size that exceeds the 300 KB area, your browser would lose connection. Anything lower than that would upload immediatly, you hit the upload button in no moments you're redirected to the page of your image.**

The website address is http://img.kfirprods.com/Upload.aspx

As for my web.config, I tried all these suggestions to change execution time and maxRequestLength but none of these helped, with both modest sizes and unmodest sizes. The default settings for the requestLength is about 4MB and the user-server connection is lost way before that. This is my web.config

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <machineKey
    validationKey="EEF33150A048D162D22CB36E1CB9956B148C7A4E6999D0F05B53D416D7A16F83823DD626F501DD3549D3E5DCB473634739D0AD9A07F71560946498C943A7586D"
    decryptionKey="0E95F75864047EB6322EA7D5246F2C1175D77A1B016F293C3BAAD000299A3DC8"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES" />

  </system.web>


</configuration>
```

There were others httpRuntime settings but even the default settings, which should work - don't. **However, what exactly happens is that the server behaves as if it's down but it will only be down to the user who exceeded that small size of upload and return after a minute or two. Please, anyone who's even a bit of an expert - try to upload some 'heavy' picture and see if you recognize the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Put following in your web.config file

```
 <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

by default the value is 4096 = 4mb. However, on shared hosting individual hosts might configure a different value and it limits the size of file that you can upload.

Further, you can/cannot modify these settings depending on the permissions given by your host.

Comment: I already tried modifying the maxRequestLength. The host provider do not limit the uploads, and even uploading 10MB at the same time went well. It's just lately that this things happen. Your suggestion didn't work, then. I let it remain the way you suggested, however, for the little chance that it would make a difference for other people (http://img.kfirprods.com/Upload.aspx)

Comment: Can you please provide the error details. I tried uploading an image but could not. However, it appears that it is not an asp.net error but some issue with iis. If you go to your root of your hosting account, you will be able to see the logs and the details of errors might be there. Please go through it, it should help you resolving the issue.

Comment: Someone managed to upload a 514KB image (not sure who), however I'm sure he would say it was very slow at some point. I'll try to do what you suggested and come back with an answer. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: I also just managed to upload blue flowers image. It is pretty big though but I could upload. The upload was quite slow though

Comment: It is of 514 kb, probably it was me.

Comment: The slowness / "timeout" come off from the same reason. Yet the reason has yet to have revealed itself and it is obviously something that started about a week ago.

Comment: I would still suggest that you investigate logs. They will reveal the reason of failed requests.

Comment: Couldn't find any good logs, only one log that displays exact traffic (Like who was where. Some website uses a picture from the website so it showed me the website's address)

Answer (score 0):

Please set Server.ScriptTimeout to longer value like

```
 Server.ScriptTimeout=36000
```

with adding

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="9999" />
```

setting in webconfig. Please let me know if this does not work

Comment: Didn't help. I'm keeping it in the code for the little chance it might make a difference in combination with other solutions

Answer (score 0):

The uploading limit of ASP.NET FileUploader is 4MB. But you can increase the limit of length of uploaded file by adding the following code into your web.config:

```
<configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It's also a good idea to ADD **executiontimeout**

```
<configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" executiontimeout="700" />
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That is about the same suggestion as everyone's and as I mentioned I already tried the simple ways. Not only that, - the uploads are stuck way lower than the default 4MB and way earlier than they should. Thsi is not the way.

Comment: Maybe if you can provide us some error codes, we can address the real problem here. But if your problem is that the server slows down when someone upload a photo, then there could be another area that we should also consider like the server settings, etc..

Comment: It's not that it slows down, it actually stops the connection with the client (usually). There is no ERROR but you can notice how the browser stops recognizing the website when uploading a picture that is over 300KB. If you upload a 300KB file it's immediate, yet about 50 KB more and something's going wrong. Try it yourself, upload a 'heavy' picture and open some other page, your browser will tell you it doesn't recognize it. However I should remind that it wasn't this way about two weeks ago, you could upload 10MB in a few moments, and of course no "crash" would have happened.

Answer (score 0):

I will ask the host provider (HostGator) if they know anything about it, again (the first customer support guy didn't seem to know much at all). If it won't work, I might as well give up, it's not like there are not enough image uploading websites on the web. Thanks for those who tried to help!